# Django REST Framework Bad Request 400

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

При отправке запроса серверу от CreateAPIView происходит Bad Request 400. Как исправить ошибку?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class CustomManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, phone_number, full_name=None):
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, full_name=full_name)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, phone_number, full_name=None):
        return self._create_user(phone_number, full_name)

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, full_name=None):
        return self._create_user(phone_number, full_name)


class UserAccount(models.Model): #CUSTOM USER
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, null=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(name="full_name", null=True, max_length=60, help_text="ФИО")
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomManager()

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        """
        Always return False. This is a way of comparing User objects to
        anonymous users.
        """
        return False

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        """
        Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
        authenticated in templates.
        """
        return True
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UserAccount

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ('phone_number', 'full_name')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .serializers import UserSerializer

class CreateUserAPIView(APIView):
    # Allow any user (authenticated or not) to access this url
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы передаете `phone_number` через параметры, а нужно положить его в `body`

Comment: Тот же результат